# Print a string message within a error message in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

How to print a string keyword from an error message.

I just want to print "Bad Request" (in this case) from the error message

> "400 - Bad Request URL: put:http://x/y/z Message: Http failure
>   response for http://x/y/z: 400 Bad Request Details: "Bad Request""

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this error message is coming from your back end (during an API call or something).

Angular has something called an HttpInterceptor that you can implement to handle all kinds of things, notably, error handling.

Example of basic [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor):

```
@Injectable()
export class MyHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    private readonly _router: Router;
    constructor(_router: Router) {
        this._router = _router;
    }

    intercept( _request: HttpRequest<any>, _next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const req = _request.clone();
        return _next.handle(req).pipe(catchError( (_error: HttpErrorResponse, _caught: any) => {
            switch ( _error.status ) {
                case 400:
                    console.error('Bad Request');
                    break;
                case 401:
                    console.log('Unauthorized. Redirecting to Login');
                    break;
                case 403:
                    console.error('Access Denied');
                    break;
                case 404:
                    console.error('Resource not found');
                    break;
                case 500:
                    console.error('Interval Server Error');
                    break;
            }
            return of(_error);
        })) as any;
    }
}
```

You can then wire this up in your `app.module.ts`

```
providers: [
   {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MyHttpInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
]
```

There's a bunch of other use cases for HttpInterceptors such as applying headers to each request (`withCredentials` or something like), but it's commonly used for catching errors.

If all you want is to print the *message* of the error, you can do this (assuming it's of the type [HttpErrorResponse](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse))

`HttpErrorResponse.message`

Here is the class:

```
class HttpErrorResponse extends HttpResponseBase implements Error {
  constructor(init: { error?: any; headers?: HttpHeaders; status?: number; statusText?: string; url?: string; })
  name: 'HttpErrorResponse'
  message: string
  error: any | null
  ok: false

  // inherited from common/http/HttpResponseBase
  constructor(init: { headers?: HttpHeaders; status?: number; statusText?: string; url?: string; }, defaultStatus: number = 200, defaultStatusText: string = 'OK')
  headers: HttpHeaders
  status: number
  statusText: string
  url: string | null
  ok: boolean
  type: HttpEventType.Response | HttpEventType.ResponseHeader
}
```